# JQuery - single validation for all inputs like (texts, checkboxes, radiobuttons ... )

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, input

I wanted to use a function that will get all the `input` in only one,
This is my code:

```
  $('button[type="submit"]').click(function() {
        var ret = true;
        $(form).find('input[required], select[required], textarea[required]').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '' && !$(this).is(':checked')) {
                alert($(this).is(':checked'));
                $(this).focus();
                $(this).addClass('border-danger');
                $.messageHandler.showMessageBox('warning_required');
                return ret = false;
            }
            $(this).removeClass('border-danger');
        });
        return ret;
 });
```

But It is not working, like the first `input[type="text"]` even if it has a value it still focuses that `input` rather than focusing other text, checkbox or radio buttons. Even if I use `||` its still not working.

Comment: create fiddle for your code and add html too!!

Comment: :checked is worked only for checkbox and radio button

Comment: @RajeshKumar I wanted them to be together in one `if` is there a possibility to do that?

Comment: So you have to first check input type then get the value like if textbox or text area then you have to get value and if type is radio or check box then you to check ':checked' attribute